# Why is Eigen not making a copy when I return by value if copy elision is deactivated?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I currently have the very simple program. I deactivated copy elision in my compiler and as far as I understand it shouldn't even apply here because the compiler doesn't know what I will input. Now, the very weird thing is that when I look at the addresses they match what I would expect if no copy was happening with the value that is returned by the function. However, THERE is a copy happening when I say `Eigen::MatrixXf m2 = m`. I have no idea why the adresses match as inutitively I expect there to be a copy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

Eigen::MatrixXf no_copy(){
    Eigen::MatrixXf m =  Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(3,3);
    Eigen::MatrixXf m2 = Eigen::MatrixXf::Random(3,3);
    int c = 0;
    std::cin >> c;
    
    
    std::cout << "m" << &m(0,0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "m2" << &m2(0,0) << std::endl;
    if (c > 0) {
        std::cout << "m " << std::endl;
        return m;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "m2 " << std::endl;
        return m2;
    }
    
    return m;
}

int main() {

    //make a 1000 x 1000 matrix of random floats
    Eigen::MatrixXf m;
    m = no_copy();
    Eigen::MatrixXf m2 = m;

    
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
    std::cout << &m(0,0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << &m2(0,0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`

I tried doing `Eigen::MatrixXf m2 = std::move(m);` to see if a move was the reason for the odd behavior, but I got an assertion error when I tried it. Why isn't Eigen copying the matrix that is returned in the `no_copy` function?

Answer (score 4):

`Eigen::MatrixXf` holds a matrix of a dynamically chosen size. Therefore it can't be storing the matrix elements directly inside its own storage. It must be using a dynamic allocation, the same way that `std::vector` does.

`return m;`, if NRVO is not applied, will use the move constructor to construct the temporary result object of the function call and `m = no_copy();` will also use the move assignment operator to assign from this temporary. If the move operations are implemented properly, they will not do any additional allocation, but instead just take over ownership of the dynamic allocation that the original `MatrixXf` made.

You are printing addresses into the dynamic allocation, which shouldn't have changed.

---

`Eigen::MatrixXf m2 = m;` is copy-construction, not move-construction, so it can't do the same. It needs to make a new dynamic allocation and copy over the values. The addresses must be different. Copy elision is also impossible.

---

`Eigen::MatrixXf m2 = std::move(m);` results in an error because you are still trying to index into `m` afterwards although you have moved from it and its dynamic allocation isn't owned by `m` anymore.